# Crystal Report file deployment from Class Library project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, crystal-reports

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution which is multi-layered.

In one of those projects  (which is not the main project and is actually a Class library) i have a Crystal Report file which i want to be included in the deployment of the application.
I tried several settings with no success.

How can i achieve deploying this report file without "hacking" around (without copying into main project ) or using other "obscure" ways...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the report has to be configured in its build action as an embedded resource. 
Calling the report has to be done through its class name (instantiating and so on). Then in the reportviewer object the source has to be set to this report object.

Loading a report would NOT work because of the nature of the project: it's a class library.